# How to get the count of JSON items using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I just don't know how to walk the JSON tree in C# using JObjects. Thanks to anyone who can guide me.

Comment: "I've tried many things and nothing is working". Please [edit] your post with those examples, such as with a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft.Json LINQ to JSON provides a number of methods for getting data from its objects. You can use linq with  a json array the same way as you could use it with a c# array. You can find more examples here https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

var quantity = ((JArray)JObject.Parse(orderDetailsResponse.Content)["cart"]["items"])
.Sum(i =>(int) i["quantity"]); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great. Can you just explain what the .Sum part is doing and how that syntax works?